# Single Page Application in AWS CloudFront

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I am having a Single Page static website which is hosted in AWS bucket.
The application is JavaScript.

I have setup Cloudfront for providing the content. 
The contents of the website is hosted in an AWS S3 bucket and Cloudfront is used to provide faster delivery of web content for users in different location.

But after setting up the website I am facing an issue. If I refresh the page, it will throw me the error as key is not present. 
I cannot refresh the page or copy the URL and paste it in another tab in the browser to access the same page.

I am getting the following error:

```
<Error>
    <Code>NoSuchKey</Code>
    <Message>The specified key does not exist.</Message>
    <Key>__build__/home</Key>
    <RequestId>36941111717B2006</RequestId>   <HostId>wfLt17lDjXhZLqCxRM2zOiDIJSF03/HKdL3V9Oeq3r1glowmlZpavRj0zzBzBgXlXZudiXoc=</HostId>
</Error>
```

And my S3 buckets redirection rules are as follows:

```
<RoutingRules>
    <RoutingRule>
        <Condition>
            <KeyPrefixEquals>*/</KeyPrefixEquals>
        </Condition>
        <Redirect>
            <ReplaceKeyWith>index.html</ReplaceKeyWith>
        </Redirect>
    </RoutingRule>
</RoutingRules>
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If your single page website properly handles 404's you can simply override the default CloudFront settings with a custom error page for your distribution, which then is your `index.html`.

You can set this up in the `Error Pages` tab for your distribution and it would look something like this:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I am having one more doubt
Take for instance if the url is <url>/blog or <url>/about and when we refresh the page it will first go through index.html and then it will load the /blog or /about page.

Comment: Yes that is correct, and how SPA:s usually work. What behaviour would be optimal?

Comment: Please correct me if I am wrong, is it possible to load the page directly without loading the index.html? So that we can have the the requested page to load fast.

Comment: @Bidyut I don't know how you website is built, do the different pages have their own static files?

Comment: Ya, different pages have different static files. Its calling some js scripts

Comment: @Bidyut in that case the above answer is a good fallback. What's the directory structure? Is it like /blog and then you have an index.html in that one?

Comment: no, there is no index.html inside /blog or other subdirectories.

Comment: @Bidyut in that case the above provided solution is the best option :)

Comment: How to ignore certain paths such as backen api paths? It is not good at all to serve index.html with 200 instead of 404 on the backend.

Comment: @adam this answer was for single page applications (without SSR) specifically.

Comment: @KarlLaurentiusRoos my question is about a real world usage, having multiple CloudFront Behaviors. One for the single page app and one for the backend services such as authentication etc.

Comment: @adam if you have CloudFront in front of a backend I don't see the need for custom rules. As the backend can determine that behaviour by itself, or am I missing something?

Comment: @KarlLaurentiusRoos the custom rule is needed for the SPA (to have nonexistent S3 objects served as index.thml, for example a `/settings` route). But this rule overrides ALL 404 statuses even the ones sent from the backend. This is the problem.

Comment: @adam an SPA without SSR has a single entry point into the application (usually index.html) and a client side router which would handle the 404, this solution applies to that. For proper 404s you would need SSR.